# Create table in PHP

Tags: php, database

and thank you for this wonderful community. Trying to make some simple social network, as a practice.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Promeni šifru</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <?php
       $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS baza";
   mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
   $tab = "CREATE TABLE Korisnici (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
  reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 )";

 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","baza");
 mysqli_query ($conn, $tab);
        $unesi = @$_POST ['unesi'];
        $em  = (@$_POST['email']);
        $pas  = (@$_POST['oldpass']);
        $pas2  = (@$_POST['oldpassagain']);

        $imei  = (@$_POST['imeip']);
        $brt  = (@$_POST['brtel']);
        $d = date("d-m-Y");
  //  $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO baza VALUES('$em','$pas','$imei','$brt','$d')");
    if ($pas!==$pas2) {
     echo("pogrešno unesena šifra");
   }

        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>


  <style media="screen">
  label {color: #0000ff; font-weight: bold; display: block; width: 160px; float: left; } label:after { content: ": " }
  </style>
  <form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email"> <label> Upišite Vaš e- mail </label> <br> <br>
    <input type="password" name="oldpass"><label> Upišite novu šifru </label> <br> <br>
    <input type="password" name="oldpassagain"><label> Ponovite novu šifru </label> <br> <br>
    <input type="text" name="imeip"> <label> Unesite ime i prezime </label><br> <br>
    <input type="number" name="brtel"> <label> Unesite broj telefona </label><br> <br>
     <input type="submit" name="unesi" value="Unesi"> <br> <br>
     </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

I have following problem.

This code is NOT working,

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS baza";
   mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
   $tab = "CREATE TABLE Korisnici (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(50),
 )";
```

It means when i delete timestamp line, it do not work. Can someone explain to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a trailing comma which you haven't deleted.

`email VARCHAR(50),`

It means the end of your query looks like this: `(50),)` which isn't valid.

Delete that comma, and the query should be valid.

Comment: Thank you very much!